# SQL Nested Query with invalid relation error (ORA-00920 Error)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `3 tables` in total. I am trying to select the price of the cost food has to be the highest and the category name have to fall under organic.

I have came up with the following `SQL QUERY` but i have received an invalid relation error.

Could someone point me out what the problem might be ?

Thanks

```
SELECT PRICE, LABEL
FROM FOOD
WHERE FOOD.FOOD_ID = (
    SELECT FOOD_ID
    FROM FOOD_CATEGORY
    WHERE FOOD_CATEGORY.FOOD_ID = (
       SELECT FOOD_ID
       FROM CATEGORY
       WHERE NAME = 'ORGANIC'
    )
);
```

**FOOD**

- FOOD_ID
- LABEL
- PRICE

**FOOD_CATEGORY**

- FOOD_ID
- CATEGORY_ID

**CATEGORY**

- CATEGORY_ID
- NAME

***Relationship***

```
FOOD.FOOD_ID = FOOD_CATEGORY.FOODID 

FOOD_CATEGORY.CATEGORYID = CATEGORY.CATEGORYID
```

Comment: Your subqueries are presumably returning more than one row, so you need `in` rather than `=`.  But, you should really learn to write this query using explicit `join` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you have more foods that are of category 'ORGANIC'. Otherwise there is no need for the table FOOD_CATEGORY. The table FOOD_CATEGORY is there to create a many-to-many relation.

So why not :

```
SELECT PRICE, LABEL
FROM FOOD
JOIN FOOD_CATEGORY ON (FOOD_CATEGORY.FOOD_ID = FOOD.FOOD_ID)
JOIN CATEGORY ON (CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID = FOOD_CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID)
WHERE CATEGORY.NAME = 'ORGANIC';
```

Or use IN instead of =

```
SELECT PRICE, LABEL
FROM FOOD
WHERE FOOD.FOOD_ID IN (
    SELECT FOOD_ID
    FROM FOOD_CATEGORY
    WHERE FOOD_CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID = (
       SELECT CATEGORY_ID
       FROM CATEGORY
       WHERE NAME = 'ORGANIC'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe How do i futher add MAX(Price) into the statement. Would a GROUP BY work ?

Comment: GROUP BY is the way to go

Comment: Try it. Takes less time then posting on SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

because its `CATEGORY_ID` instead of `FOOD_ID`

```
SELECT PRICE, LABEL
FROM FOOD
WHERE FOOD.FOOD_ID = (
    SELECT FOOD_ID
    FROM FOOD_CATEGORY
    WHERE FOOD_CATEGORY.FOOD_ID = (
       SELECT CATEGORY_ID
       FROM CATEGORY
       WHERE NAME = 'ORGANIC'
    )
);
```